# Convergence in $S'(\mathbb R^d)$ of the paraproduct $\dot{T}_uv$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, harmonic-analysis, fourier-transform, schwartz-distributions, tempered-distributions

Let $B = B(0,4/3)$, $C = \{x \in \mathbb R^d : 3/4 \leq \|x\|_2 \leq 8/3\}$ and $\tilde{C} = \{x \in \mathbb R^d : 1/12 \leq \|x\|_2 \leq 10/3\}$.

For a fixed Littlewood-Paley decomposition $\chi \in \mathcal{D}(B)$, $\varphi \in \mathcal{D}(C)$, we denote by $\dot{S}_j := \chi(2^{-j}D)$ the homogeneous low-frequency cut-off operator and $\dot{\Delta}_j := \varphi(2^{-j}D)$ the homogeneous dyadic block operator. Moreover, we define the following subspace of tempered distributions:

$$S'_h = \{u \in S'(\mathbb R^d) : \lim \limits_{j \to -\infty}\|\dot{S_j}u\|_{\mathcal{L}^{\infty}(\mathbb R^d)} = 0\}$$

Here, I'm reading and using the notations from "Fourier Analysis and Nonlinear Partial Differential Equations", Chapter 2.2 p.59, by H. Bahouri.

In Chapter 2.6 p.86, the homogeneous paraproduct of two tempered distributions $u, v \in S'(\mathbb R^d)$ is formally defined as:

$$\dot{T}_uv = \sum_{j \in \mathbb Z}\dot{S}_{j-1}u \dot{\Delta}_j v$$

Remark 2.46 from p.86 claims that if $u,v \in S'_h$, then $\dot{T}_uv$ makes sense in $S'(\mathbb R^d)$, i.e. the sum $\langle \dot{T}_uv , f \rangle$ converges in $\mathbb R$ for any $f \in S(\mathbb R^d)$. However, I'm unable to prove such a claim or find a reference proving it.

I know that $\dot{S}_{j-1}u \dot{\Delta}_j v$ is a tempered distribution whose Fourier transform is supported in the annulus $2^j \tilde{C}$. In particular, it is a smooth function with at most polynomial growth (independent of $j$, I believe). Similar statements can be made about $\dot{S}_{j-1}u$ and $\dot{\Delta}_j v$.

I also know that for $u \in S'_h$, we have the decomposition $$u = \lim \limits_{j \to +\infty} \dot{S}_j u = \sum_{j \in \mathbb Z} \dot{\Delta}_ju$$ in the space $S'(\mathbb R^d)$.

However, I didn't succeed in combining any of these pieces of information together.

Comment: Lemma 3 in Chapter 16 of Coifman-Meyer's Wavelets: Calderón-Zygmund and Multilinear Operators is used to prove just this for the inhomogeneous paraproduct. It might be worth looking at to see if you could extend that argument to work in your case. Granted, this comment may no longer be relevant a year later...